# How to convert multidimensional array to collections into Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

From an API I have a response a multidimensional array like:

[image]

How I can convert this array to eloquent object so I can access in view with `$collection->Query->Country or $collection->Carriers->where('id',12345) ...`

I try with:

```
$res1 = collect($res1)->map(function($row) {
    return collect($row);
});

dd($res1);
```

but no success!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Write your code, don't put an image.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use

```
$collection['Carriers']->where('id',12345)
// or
collect($collection['Carriers'])->where('id',12345)
```

For make new Eloquent model with attributes you can use

```
$query =  (new Query())->setRawAttributes($collection['Query']);
```

then usage

```
$query->Country;
```

Or you can do it with this rough way

```
$model = (new Model())->setRawAttributes($res1);
```

and usage as you mentioned

```
$model->Query->Country or $model->Carriers->where('id',12345)
```

Comment: I got Call to a member function where() on array

Comment: use `collect($collection['Carriers'])->where('id',12345)`